# Why is this quotient space the zero space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, quotient-spaces

The text says “The quotient space $V/V$ is the zero space as $x+V=V$ for all $x \in V$.
I can only seem to think of $V/V = \{V\}$, since the coset $x+V$ (with $x \in V$) always represents the set $V$ itself.

Comment: And in the quotient, $V$ is the identity element.

Comment: Okay! I see that. Then what is the quotient space $V/ \{0\}$? I thought that is also $\{V\}$?

Comment: $V/\{0\}$ is (isomorphic to) $V$, very different from $\{V\}$.

Comment: @Thorgott can you explain this particular isomorphism / provide a link where it is explained?

Comment: The vector $v\in V$ corresponds to the coset $v+\{0\}\in V/\{0\}$. This is just the quotient map $V\rightarrow V/\{0\}$, so linear and surjective by definition. Checking that it is injective is saying that the equivalence classes are singletons, which you can check from the definition.

Comment: @Thorgott We can also say that this map (say T) is injective because the only element of $V/ \{0\}$ for which the image in $V$ is 0, is $\{0\}$, that is Ker $T = \{0\}$?

Comment: Careful. I gave a map $V\rightarrow V/\{0\}$, not $V/\{0\}\rightarrow V$, so "the image in $V$ of an element of $V/\{0\}$" is not well-defined a priori. But if you want to say that the only vector in $V$ mapping to the zero element $\{0\}\in V/\{0\}$ is the zero vector $0\in V$, then yes, that's true and pretty much the same argument as what I suggested above once spelled out.

Comment: Oops sorry, a mistake on my part. But yes, I got it now.

Answer (score 2):

You are right: $V/V$ consists of a single element, which is $V$. And the only vector space with a single element is the zero space.

Besides, note that, in $V/V$,\begin{align}V+V&=(0+V)+(0+V)\\&=(0+0)+V\\&=0+V\\&=V.\end{align}So, $V$ is the null vector of $V/V$ (as it would be expected).